# Create columns based on the proportion of detections that occurred in a given treatment

Tags: r

Sample data are as follows

```
data <- structure(list(animal.ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4), sex = c("m", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "m"), treatment = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "A", "A","NA", "NA"), conflict = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

I would like to create one new column for each treatment, which calculates the proportion of animal.ID detections that occur in a treatment for each unique animal.ID (For example, the new proportion column for treatment A [lets call it prop.A] for animal.ID 1 would be .50, because 50% of its detections occurred in treatment A...see desired output below).

In addition, I would like to create a "match" column, that denotes whether a conflict occurred for an animal that was ALSO detected in any treatment.

Finally, I'd like to create a new column that counts the number of times an animal occurs.

I'd like to collapse the dataframe so there are no duplicate animal.ID's in the dataframe.

For animals that have **solely** NA as their treatment, they would get 0's for the new proportion columns.

My desired output is as follows:

```
data <- structure(list(animal.ID = c(1, 2,3,4), sex = c("m", "f", "f", "m"), detection.frequency = c(4, 4, 3, 1), match = c(0, 0, 1, 0), prop.A = c(".50","0","1","0"), prop.B = c(".25","0","0","0"), prop.C = c(".25","1","0","0")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Note: I have additional columns in my dataframe (e.g., sex) that I would like to retain.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps. Note that the `NA`s in treatment are character strings `"NA"`, convert them to `<NA>` to get the right behavior of `table`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data$treatment[data$treatment == "NA"] <- NA

data %>% 
  summarize(sex = unique(sex), 
            detection.frequency = n(), 
            match = +(any(conflict == 1) & !all(is.na(treatment))), 
            prop = list(proportions(table(treatment))), .by = animal.ID) %>% 
  unnest_wider(prop, names_repair=function(x) 
                       c(x[1:4], paste0("prop.", x[5:7]))) %>% 
  mutate(replace(., is.na(.), as.table(0)))
# A tibble: 4 × 7
  animal.ID sex   detection.frequency match prop.A      prop.B      prop.C     
      <dbl> <chr>               <int> <int> <table[1d]> <table[1d]> <table[1d]>
1         1 m                       4     0 0.5         0.25        0.25       
2         2 f                       4     0 0.0         0.00        1.00       
3         3 f                       3     1 1.0         0.00        0.00       
4         4 m                       1     0 0.0         0.00        0.00
```

Comment: Thank you @Andre Wildberg! Though, its not quite what I'm looking for. The "match" column receives a 1 only if the animal was detected any treatment AS WELL AS encountered conflict. So, animal #4 would receive a 0 under match because it was not detected in any of the treatments. Additionally, I do not want a prop.NA column, because I do not want NAs to be considered a treatment.

Comment: Yeah, gonna edit. To clarify, group 3 match conflict is for `NA` right? So the conflict is not assigned by row but counts for the group?

Comment: Thanks Andre. Anima.ID 3 should receive a 1 (binary) under the new column 'match' because it fulfills the following conditions: 1) it was detected in any of the treatments, AND 2) it encountered conflict. By contrast, animal.ID 4 was not detected in any of the treatments, and animal.ID's 1 and 2 did not encounter conflict, so they receive a 0 for 'match'.

Comment: Got it, thx. Also I found that `NA` in treatment was just a character string but it needs to be `<NA>`. Gonna mention it in edit.

Comment: See edit, should now be what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions with data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
```

You are trying to do 3 separate things:

1 count the number of times an animal.ID occurs

```
data[ , .(detection.frequency = .N), by=.(animal.ID, sex)]
```

2 get the proportion of the animal.ID's accross treatments, ignoring NA's

```
longdat <- data[!is.na(treatment), .(count = .N), by=.(animal.ID, treatment)]
longdat[, prop := count/sum(count), by=animal.ID]

tidyr::pivot_wider(longdat, 
                   id_cols = "animal.ID", 
                   names_from = "treatment", 
                   values_from = "prop",
                   values_fill = 0)
```

3 flag animal.ID's by your 'match' criteria

```
data[ , .(match = sum(conflict==1) * sum(!is.na(treatment)) > 0), by=animal.ID]
```

Comment: Thank you @DanY! Definitely getting there, however, this approach does not create a new dataframe with the columns of interest, nor does it retain other columns I'd like to keep (for example, sex).

Comment: That's right: teaching someone to fish will get them farther than simply providing them with one fish now! While other solutions here take you straight to the answer, I sought to demonstrate why the request is complicated (hint: because it's actually 3 requests) , and to show how accomplish each.  You can simply merge() -- or even just cbind() -- the three solutions I provided to get your desired data.frame.  I assume your actual dataset is larger than the example data provided, and you should not blindly copy SO code for use on that bigger dataset without understanding how it the code works.

Comment: Noted - thank you for providing your reasoning behind this.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

count_data <- data |> group_by(animal.ID) |> count(name = "detection.frequency")

data |>
  mutate(conflict = as.numeric(conflict)) |> 
  count(animal.ID, sex, treatment, conflict) |>
  group_by(animal.ID, sex) |> 
  mutate(prop = n/sum(n)) |> 
  select(-n) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "treatment", values_from = "prop", 
              names_prefix = "prop.", values_fill = 0) |> 
  mutate(match = ifelse((conflict > 0) & (prop.NA != 1), 1, 0)) |> 
  select(-prop.NA) |> 
  summarize(prop.A = sum(prop.A), prop.B = sum(prop.B), 
            prop.C = sum(prop.C), match = sum(match)) |> 
  left_join(count_data)
```

This works on the data provided but not tested on multiple conflicts or other issues.

Comment: Thank you! This worked as well as previous answer (though, I revised by replacing |> with %>%

Comment: |> is the new native R pipe introduced in R 4.1.0.